# counting filter results in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm filtering a data set by month.  I would like to return the number of "matched" records from the following function:

```
function dateMatch(data, value) {
        var d = new Date(data.properties.Date);
        var m = month[d.getMonth()];
        if (inputValue == m) {
            this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
            return "red";
        } else {
            return "#808080";
        };
    }
```

Basically, want to count the # of appended childs in this function.  How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your function currently returns a color. Are you saying you want it to return a count instead? Also, it doesn’t look like this function is filtering `data` it’s comparing the month to a mystery variable `inputValue` And returning a color string.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable defined outside the function and increment it whenever your condition match. Make sure to initialize counter to 0 everytime you want to start the counter again.

```
var counter = 0;

function dateMatch(data, value) {
        var d = new Date(data.properties.Date);
        var m = month[d.getMonth()];
        if (inputValue == m) {
            this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
            counter++;
            return "red";
        } else {
            return "#808080";
        };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

cdoshi, thank you.  This worked:

```
var counter = 55
function dateMatch(data, value) {
        var d = new Date(data.properties.Date);
        var m = month[d.getMonth()];
        if (inputValue == m) {
            this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
            counter++;
            return "red";
        } else {
            return "#808080";
        };


        return counter
    }
```

And then, I output the counter variable, so it changes when the time-slider is initiated :

```
 <div id="sliderContainer">
        <input id="timeslide" type="range" min="0" max="11" value="0" step="1" /><br>
        <span id="range" style="font-family:optima"; >January</span>
    </div>

var inputValue = null;
    var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

d3.select("#timeslide").on("input", function() {
        update(+this.value);
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter
    });
```

This works as expected, but the only issue is that if the time-slider goes in reverse order, the count continues to update incrementally.  I only want it to sum until the last month, Dec, at the end of the time slider, and if the user goes in reverse, the counts will begin decreasing again.

Comment: I am slightly confused. Where are you calling the dateMatch function? Also, it would be great if you can create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score -1):

It is a lot cleaner to get rid of these global `counter` and `inputVariable` variables and let d3 count the `selected` items.

Instead of setting a color on the `selected` items give them the class `selected`.

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = d3.selectAll(".incident.selected").size();
```

Pass the required month as an argument to the selector function.

```
function dateMatch(monthIdx) {
    return function (d) {
        return (new Date(d.properties.Date).getMonth() === monthIdx);
    }
}
```

In the update function

```
function update(monthIdx) {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = month[monthIdx];
    d3.selectAll(".incident")
      .classed("selected", dateMatch(monthIdx))
      //.attr( "d", geoPath.pointRadius(dateMatchRadius) )
      ;
}
```

I have commented out the `geopath` call in the update method because it is not relevant in the example snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<style>
.incident {fill:#808080;}
.incident.selected {fill:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sliderContainer">
<input id="timeslide" type="range" min="0" max="11" value="0" step="1" /><br>
<div>Month: <span id="range" style="font-family:optima;">January</span></div>
<div>Count: <span id="count"></span></div>
<svg id="chart" width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script>
var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

var data = d3.range(200)
             .map(d => { return {properties: {Date: new Date(Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)+1990, Math.floor(Math.random() * 12), 1).toString()} }; });

d3.select("#chart")
  .selectAll(".incident")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "incident")
  .attr("cx", d => (Math.random() * 400)+50)
  .attr("cy", d => (Math.random() * 400)+50)
  .attr("r",  d => (Math.random() * 10)+5);

function dateMatch(monthIdx) {
    return function (d) {
        return (new Date(d.properties.Date).getMonth() === monthIdx);
    }
}

function update(monthIdx) {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = month[monthIdx];
    d3.selectAll(".incident")
      .classed("selected", dateMatch(monthIdx))
      //.attr( "d", geoPath.pointRadius(dateMatchRadius) )
      ;
}

d3.select("#timeslide").on("input", function() {
    update(+this.value);
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = d3.selectAll(".incident.selected").size();
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```